# vue 3 unable to access data object in method

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm getting an error with my vue3 app. I'm trying to make a function in the `methods{}` block which hits dynamodb, and creates a listmap of data, which I want to pass to a child component with props. I am calling the function that communicates with dynamoDB in the `created(){}` block.

I'm not quite at the part of passing the data. Instead, I'm getting the following errors when trying to populate the `productsData` object in the `data(){}` block.

I'm setting the type of my `products` `prop` to be an interface I defined.

I am then casting that `productsData` `data` object to the `products` `prop` type.

For some reason, I am unable to `push()` maps to the `this.productsData` object as it is `undefined`.

Here's the error

```
[Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "products" 
  at <Home onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6589
TypeError: _this.productsData is undefined
```

html:

```html
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <HelloWorld :key="key" :products="products" />
  </div>
</template>
```

typescript code:

```html
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, PropType } from "vue";
import { DynamoDBClient, QueryCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
import { fromCognitoIdentityPool } from "@aws-sdk/credential-providers";
import DBResponse from "@/interfaces/DBResponse";
import HelloWorld from "@/components/HelloWorld.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
  props: {
    products: {
      type: Object as PropType<DBResponse[]>,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      key: 0,
      productsData: this.products,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    forceRerender() {
      this.key += 1;
    },
    async getProductData() {
      const region = process.env.VUE_APP_AWS_REGION as string;
      const clientDynamoDB = new DynamoDBClient({
        region,
        credentials: fromCognitoIdentityPool({
          identityPoolId: process.env.VUE_APP_IDENTITY_POOL_ID as string,
          accountId: process.env.VUE_APP_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID,
          clientConfig: { region },
        }),
      });
      const query_input = {
        TableName: process.env.VUE_APP_TABLE_NAME,
        IndexName: "GSI1",
        KeyConditionExpression: "SK = :sort_key and DK1 = :data_key",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ":sort_key": { S: "PRODUCT#BLEND" },
          ":data_key": { S: "listed" },
        },
        Select: "ALL_ATTRIBUTES",
      };
      const command = new QueryCommand(query_input);
      try {
        const results = await clientDynamoDB.send(command);
        const items = results.Items;
        const cloudfrontHost = process.env.VUE_APP_CLOUDFRONT_HOST as string;
        if (items) {
          for (const key in items) {
            const item = items[key];
            this.productsData.push({
              id: item.PK.S?.split("PRODUCT#")[1],
              name: item.Name.S,
              src: cloudfrontHost.concat(
                "/products/assets/",
                item.PK.S?.split("PRODUCT#")[1] as string,
                ".png"
              ),
              description: item.Description.S,
              price: item.Price.S,
            });
          }
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      console.log(this.productsData);
      this.forceRerender();
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.getProductData();
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: Since `products` is a prop of a router-view component, I'd expect it to be set either in your route config's `prop` function, or via a query param, but it's an object array, so the URL is not an ideal medium. What went into your decision for making `products` a prop?

Comment: I'm not trying to set it in the URL I don't believe. Perhaps I am structuring things wrong. Perhaps I need this view to load the component, and have the component do the dynamodb lookup. From there, the component can emit something up to the view and force the component reload once the response is fully parsed so that my products render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`productsData` is initialized to `products`, but the `products` prop is missing (as seen in the error message), so both are `undefined`.

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70146781/vue-3-unable-to-access-data-object-in-method/70148084#comment124001776_70146781), you actually don't need the `products` prop at all. You're setting up `productsData[]` by pushing data into it in `getProductsData()` (called from `created()` hook), so the `products` prop does not even come into play.

The solution seems to be to remove the `products` prop, and initialize `productsData` to an empty array with a type assertion (`as DBResponse[]`):

```js
export default defineComponent({
  //props: {
  //  products: {
  //    type: Object as PropType<DBResponse[]>,
  //    required: true,
  //  },
  //},
  data() {
    return {
      //productsData: this.products,
      productsData: [] as DBResponse[]
    };
  },
})
```